# BIO_new_mem_buf failed to create EVP_PKEY Key``

Tags: c, openssl, private-key

I need to create a EVP_PKEY Key containing private key.
Initially Private Key in PEM format is stored in variable                                                  pKey.

Now i am trying to create a EVP_PKEY Key using BIO mem.

```
 EVP_PKEY *privkey;
 BIO *mem;
 mem = BIO_new_mem_buf(pKey, -1); 
 privkey = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(mem, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Why is PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey returning NULL?

```
 pKey contains valid Key bytes in PEM format.
```

what could be the possible reason of PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failing?

Comment: Is each line of your pKey finished with `\r\n`? It is necessary for PEM_read functions.

Comment: [ERR_print_errors()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/ERR_print_errors.html) might give more information.

Comment: The problem can also be space before `----`. See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57158003/2826535) for image...

Answer (score 1):

You might have an encrypted pKey and the passphrase is missing and/or you did not call `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();` which initializes EVP ciphers in order to decrypt an encapsulated key.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the BIO is at the end of it's contents and needs to be rewound - see https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html (under bugs)